# Does Windows 10 Home edition have Local Group Policy Object?

Tags: windows-10, group-policy

Does Windows 10 Home edition have Local Group Policy Object?

In other words, when comparing Home and Pro, for example, is it the case that:

- They both have identical LGPO, but Home does not have the editor (gpedit.msc)
- Home does not have LGPO at all
- Something in-between

Just to note, assuming LGPO exists in both versions, when I said "identical" in the first item above, I am only talking about the supporting infrastructure, not the policies themselves. Separating this just in case the engine is present, but some policies do not exist because they would apply to things that Home does not support.

I could not find authoritative documentation regarding this, I would appreciate if you could supply some that I can read through.

Comment: What pratical problem are you trying to solve

Comment: @Ramhound I am trying to apply a GPO policy, specifically [this one](https://www.windows-security.org/3730f81e1cd69dc4de0ee3b7da0337ce/allow-applications-to-prevent-automatic-sleep-on-battery), to a Windows 10 Home machine. Before diving deeper into this, I wanted to make sure I am not barking up the wrong tree. Also, I am trying to learn more about this, since GPO seem to be used a lot, so I think it will be useful for other things.

Comment: [Windows Starter Edition, Home and Home Premium do not include gpedit, how do I install it?](//superuser.com/q/1018145)

Comment: yes, but some GPOs only work in higher SKUs (Pro or Enterprise)

Comment: Thanks @DavidPostill. OK, so that somewhat clarifies that Home has some LGPO. Do you have some links to (preferably Microsoft) docs that give more details whether the difference is only policies or if there are other differences?

Comment: @icyrock.com Look for the "Group Policy Settings Reference Guide" guide link in my answer :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes. The Home Edition for Windows 8, 8.1 & 10 has full support for Local Group Policies. Only the control panel for LGP (aka `gpedit.msc`) is scrapped. I extracted one from Windows 10 Professional WIM image and run it directly. Now I have full control to LGP on My Windows 10 Home.
The same applies to Windows 8 & Windows 8.1. Not sure for Windows RT (ARM processor).

Comment: *almost* - there's at least one policy that has no effect on Home editions (the one controlling automatic updates).

Comment: Windows Update Automation is not affected _by any means_ in Windows 10 Home Edition. It's hard-coded into the system regardless of user's settings. In actuality that policy _does_ put a key in your registry but the system ignores it.

Comment: Yes, that's my point - whether it updates the registry value or not doesn't really matter if the value has no effect *depending on the edition* - which is what the question is (broadly) asking.

Comment: I am having an extra concern that, if copied directly from a professional edition image, the `gpedit.msc` will have the update automation setting removed as it's not applicable.

Comment: Thanks iBug, do you happen to have some links to (preferably Microsoft) documentation that provides more details?